# Images inserted in a question using Chrome on Android via the image uploader aren't clickable

Tags: bug, images, uploader, android, mobile-chrome

The images inserted in a question using Chrome on Android via the image uploader aren't clickable.

Example of non-clickable images: [Why did Myanmar get removed from the list of countries on the international driving permit issued by the AAA sometime between 2016 and 2019?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/148421/1810)

Comment: Is the markdown for images editable afterward? Then only some brackets need to be inserted, no?